# In Heroku; how to transfer 2 apps from Team to Personal?

Tags: heroku, heroku-api, heroku-ci

I do not want to be charged, reason why I want to switch my project from team to personal.

This is what I am doing right now:

1)  I created a new app called radix-haven-corp (This is app is under my personal account)

[image]

2) These are my actual apps, which are running through a Team account (Apparently, this is charge featured by Heroku)

[image]

3) I am doing this:

- I go to my setting into my Team Account:
- I clicked on Transfer apps:
- When I clicked on Transfer apps, it sends my new app called radix-haven-corp (the one inside my personal account) to my Team account.

Please help. How can I transfers my apps to my personal account to use free Dynos?

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it right.

Select the team where the app exists
Select the app or go here https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/[yourappname]/settings
On the app menu select settings
Scroll down to transfer ownership
Select the new owner, since this is done in the app settings the system already knows what app is your target.
[Screen shot of ownership menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qp1O.png)